# How to pass function array into js function

Tags: javascript

How could I get to display "Big Mac"

This [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_object_constructor) makes it look like this should work. Not sure where I went wrong.

```js
function sandwich(name, price, quantity, meal) {
  this.name = "Default Sandwich";
  this.price = 0.00;
  this.quantity = 0;
  this.meal = false;
}

var burger = new sandwich("Big Mac", 1.25, 1, false);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = burger.name;
```

```html
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

Comment: My opinion is to use `json` as the argument. or in html the array may not available. Please check

Comment: You never set properties !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change your `sandwich()` function:

```
function sandwich(name, price, quantity, meal) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.quantity = quantity;
  this.meal = meal;
}
```